# convert cat results to data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I need plot in r the iterations obtained using While, the results are obtained by cat, How do I convert the results in data frame to plot them?

```
f <- 5
n <- 0
while(f > 0.001)
{
n <- n + 1
f <- f / n
cat(f,n,"\n")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you need to use `cat`? You can achieve this without it:

```
f <- 5
n <- 0
results <- data.frame( n = n, f = f )

while( f > 0.001) {
    n <- n + 1
    f <- f / n

    results <- rbind( results, c( n, f ) )
}
```

Basically, you start a `dataframe`, then add a row to it for every run of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient way but will work:

```
f <- 5
f_vector <-f
n <- 0
n_vector <- n
results =data.table(n,f)
while(f > 0.001)
{
  n <- n + 1
  n_vector=c(n,n_vector)
  f <- f / n
  f_vector=c(f,f_vector)

   cat(f,n,"\n")
}
result=data.table(n_vector,f_vector)
```